# where does the DHCP options information send by the DHCP Server will be stored in the linux machine?

Tags: c, linux, dhcp

I have a fedora core machine. My server is sending the [DHCP option](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2132.txt) "43" ("Vendor Specific Information"). I am using DHCLIENT.

Before DHCP server sends the option "43", I'm sending the option 60 ("Vendor class Id") through dhclient.

My question is how do I read the DHCP option 43 value, given by the server?

Will the information be stored in a file at client side? I am planning to monitor the file using `inotify()` to know if any information is updated/added by the DHCP server.

I can send the information to DHCP server easily.

```
# sudo gvim /etc/dhcp/dhclient-em1.conf
```

Here is the content of "/etc/dhcp/dhclient-em1.conf"

```
send vendor-class-identifier "anaconda-Linux 3.1.0-7.fc16.i686 i686";
```

Comment: I think this is covered by the "Vendor Encapsulated Options" part of the [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/dhclient-options). Also, this is somewhat off-topic.

Comment: It talks about Server. I want to read the value send by the server. How can I read so.

Comment: BTW: dhcpclient is open source. You could inspect the source to see what it does.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve as fare as I kown all information den dhcpclient get from the server will be added into the leases file for the specific interface on my ubuntu 14.04 this can be found under /vat/lib/dhcp/dhclient.eth0.leases